# React Calculator (using reducer hook), issue with .match() and operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, match, reduce

I have made a basic calculator in React using the reducer hook, however, there are two issues arising:
I have the **state as {prevOperand,currentOperand,operation}**

1. In the case **where two operators are clicked consecutively**, I want to **check if the last character in the string in the currentOperand contains any of the arithematic operators so that I can return the same state back (preventing the second selected operator from entering).** However, the **.match method doesn't seem to be working**, and the return statement in the 'if' loop isn't getting executed. What might be the problem here?
2. I have used a **function for evaluating the numbers entered in currentOperand**, which returns the value of the varible "result", which is equated to the currentOperand.Afterwards, when I press any operation (or) the DEL (DELETE) button , I am getting an error. How to resolve this????

````
import { ACTIONS } from "./Actions";

var symbol ;

function reducer (state, action) { 
  symbol = ['*','.','+','-','/']
  console.log(state)
  console.log(action) 
  switch(action.type){
    case ACTIONS.ADD_DIGIT: //add digit
      return {...state, currentOperand: `${state.currentOperand || ""}${action.payload}`}  
    case ACTIONS.DELETE_DIGIT: //single digit
      return {...state, currentOperand: state.currentOperand.substring(0,state.currentOperand.length-1)}
    case ACTIONS.CLEAR:  //clear output
      return { prevOperand: null, currentOperand: 0 ,operation: null}
    case ACTIONS.CHOOSE_OPERATION: 
     if(action.payload && state.currentOperand == null) { // operation and evaluation shouldn't be the first button pressed 
        return state 
      } else if(state.currentOperand.includes('/') || state.currentOperand.includes('*') ||
      state.currentOperand.includes('+')|| state.currentOperand.includes('-')) { 
        // CHECK FOR THE ERROR FROM HERE ON --------------------------------------
          let string = state.currentOperand
          let variable = '/^[*+-/]*$/'
          console.log(string)
          if(string.charAt([string.length - 1]).match(variable)) {
            console.log("operator present")
             return state  // FIRST RETURN STATEMENT -------------------
          }
              const numbers = state.currentOperand.split(/([-+*/])/g) // the number is evaluated
              const result = evaluateNum(numbers[0], numbers[1],numbers[2])
              return {currentOperand : result} //SECOND RETURN STATEMENT -------------------
           
      } else if(action.payload ==='.' && state.currentOperand.includes('.')){ //extra decimals
        return state
      } else{ //displaying the operations
      return {...state, currentOperand: `${state.currentOperand}${action.payload}`}
     } 

    case ACTIONS.EVALUATION: //calling evaluation function (when = is pressed)
        const numbers = state.currentOperand.split(/([-+*/])/g) // the number is evaluated
        const result = evaluateNum(numbers[0], numbers[1],numbers[2])
        return {currentOperand : result} // AFTER THIS COMMAND, UNABLE TO USE ANY ARTHEMATIC OPERATORS OR 
                                       //DELETE BUTTON
    default:
      return state
   }
}
 ----------------------------UPTO HERE ------------------------------------------------------------
// evaluation function
function evaluateNum( prevOperand, operation, currentOperand){
   let prevNum = parseFloat(prevOperand)
   let currentNum = parseFloat(currentOperand)
   console.log(prevNum)
   console.log(currentNum)
   if (operation === '+'){     
       return prevNum + currentNum
   } else if(operation === '-') {
      return  prevNum - currentNum 
   } else if(operation === '*') {
      return  prevNum * currentNum
   } else if(operation === '/' && currentOperand!= '0') {
      return prevNum / currentNum
   } 
}

export default function App() {
  const [{prevOperand=null, currentOperand =0, operation=null}, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,{})
  return (
    <div className="calculator-grid">
      <div className="output">
        <div className="prev-operand">{prevOperand} {operation}</div>
        <div className="current-operand">{currentOperand}</div>
      </div>
        <button className="span-two" onClick={()=> {
          dispatch({type: ACTIONS.CLEAR , payload:null})
        }}>AC</button>
        <button onClick={()=> {
          dispatch({type: ACTIONS.DELETE_DIGIT , payload:null})
        }}>DEL</button>
        <ButtonOperation operation='/' dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="1" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="2" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="3" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonOperation operation='*' dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="4" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="5" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="6" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonOperation operation='+' dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="7" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="8" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="9" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonOperation operation='-' dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonOperation operation='.' dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="0" dispatch={dispatch}/>  
        <button className="span-two" onClick={()=> {
          dispatch({type: ACTIONS.EVALUATION , payload:'='})
        }}>=</button>
    </div>
  );
}

 </code>```

 THE ACTIONS OBJECT PASSED INTO THE REDUCER  ---->

CHOOSE_DIGIT: ADDING DIGIT TO STRING/DISPLAY

DELETE_DIGIT: REMOVE THE LAST CHARACTER ENTERED

CLEAR: EMPTY THE DISPLAY AND VARIABLES

CHOOSE_OPERATION: SELECT *, /,+,-, . (DECIMAL)

EVALUATION: PRESS = SIGN
````